# mcedit - select all text

Tags: linux, text-editors

How can I select all text in mcedit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Press <kbd>F9</kbd> to bring up the pull-down menu, <kbd>E</kbd> as in ***E**​dit*, then <kbd>A</kbd> as in *Mark **a**​ll*.